# Retrieve total amount of colors available for product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I'm using the code below in a module to retrieve the total number of available colors for a configurable product. The code retrieves the data fine however removes the swatches completely. Any help on sorting this so the swatches show as well as the total.

---

Test/Mod/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Mod\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
   if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {

         $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
         foreach ($_children as $child){
          $colorarr[$child->getColor()] = $child->getColor();
         }
         if(count($colorarr) > 0) { ?>
            <div class="color-total">
                <?php echo count($colorarr) . 'Color'; ?>
            </div>
        <?php  }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this with the code below

```
<?php

namespace Test\Mod\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
   if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {

         $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
         foreach ($_children as $child){
          $colorarr[$child->getColor()] = $child->getColor();
         }
         if(count($colorarr) > 0) { ?>
            <div class="color-total">
                <?php echo count($colorarr) . 'Color'; ?>
            </div>
        <?php  }
    }
    $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
    if ($renderer) {
        $renderer->setProduct($product);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}

}
```