# display count of color swatches in magento 2 list page

Tags: magento2, color-swatches, list.phtml

how to display the count of color swatches on the Magento 2 list page?

I have tried by a custom extension(listproduct file)
but that's not helping to solve the issue

can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/retrieve-total-amount-of-colors-available-for-product-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Override template file: **magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml** And add below code into product loop.

```
<?php
if ($_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    $colorarr = [];
    $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
      $colorarr[$child->getColor()] = $child->getColor();
    }
    $showCount = count($colorarr) - 1;
    if($showCount > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="color-total">
            <?php echo '+'.$showCount." colors"; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
<?php
}
?>
```